# fiware-orion context broker mongoDB docker

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I am trying to run Orion Context Broker on Linux Mint using docker, but i cant start it. Also I tried installing MongoDB version 3.2 also on Linux Mint using docker, but cant find any installation solution.
Can someone help me?
Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Orion, at startup, connects to Mongo. If mongo isn't accepting the connection, Orion exits. There is nothing the broker can do without its database.
So, that would explain why Orion doesn't start.
Why such an old version of Mongo?
Lastly, if you add detailed information on the problem you see, perhaps you can get some help. Without that, there's no way to help.

Comment: Why the old version of Mongo? Because my laptop doesnt support the newer version, I understand how the Orion works but i fail at connecting it to the Mongo, the reason is maybe the port that i am using, i am trying to connect to the port 1026 and i just cant... Could you maybe give me some pointers on how to start and run the Context Broker please?

Comment: So, mongo starts up fine then? That's really the thing here. If mongo can't start, then neither will Orion. v3.2 of mongo ... might work. It's very very old, but it might work. The port 1026 is the port that Orion opens for incoming REST requests. That has nothing to do with mongo. The default port for mongo is 27017 and Orion will use that port unless you tell it to use another one (with the CLI option -dbbost <IP:port number>). Post broker traces and let's see if we can do. 
See documentation on Orion and docker here: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/docker/README.md

Comment: I solved it! Thank you so much for your help! I made huge progress today, now i have to implement everything on Raspberry pi 3, for my final masters work, but thank you for your time and for your help!!!

Comment: I'd suggest to self-answer your question with a post based in the previous comment. It is better if the solution is in the proper answer post that hidden in a comment to the question post ;)